# Delphi RAD studio installer Tokyo - Android SDK installer checksum error

Tags: android, delphi, installation

```
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 26.0.2
Download finished with wrong checksum. Expected 98832431e339c82be1fe910a733a3782071200fd, got aa3ef6f18eff4b8f12dbdf980647a6ce6c2ebe8c.
```

I've tried clearing the cache is the Android SDK manager.

I did the google thing and the best was to clear cache and try again.
TIA
JAC 
p.s. this isn't for all components, a bunch of other ones downloaded and installed fine.

Comment: Best would be to ask official installation support at https://www.embarcadero.com/support Next, you can download Android SDK from official Android site https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

Comment: I agree it is kind of a CS question, but would argue it is a google one rather than an embarcadero one.  I did go to the google site, but couldn't work out if I needed the sdkManager download and if it would be the correct version etc.  I thought someone may have come accross this before and the CS route wouldn't be a shared answer.  I'll take a VM snapshot and install the official android sdkmanager and see where I get with that.  Cheers.  Any more for any more?